# Capybara with rails 6.1.4.4 element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test the presence of a field called name within capybara but it returns the below error that is the follow:

```
  1) _form filling the form filling the user elements
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'name', with: 'Leo'
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "name" that is not disabled
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:303:in `block in synced_resolve'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:83:in `synchronize'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:292:in `synced_resolve'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:53:in `find'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:91:in `fill_in'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:778:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /home/leo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/_form_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11537 seconds (files took 0.94126 seconds to load)
8 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/_form_spec.rb:7 # _form filling the form filling the user elements
```

Here is the spec that I'm trying to write:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature '_form', type: :feature do
  context 'filling the form' do
    scenario 'filling the user elements' do
      visit users_path
      fill_in 'name', with: 'Leo'
      expect(page).to have_field('name', with: 'Leo')
    end
  end
end
```

And the form that I'm creating is like that:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_with model: @user, local: true do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name%>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :email %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :age %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :age %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried all solutions here in S.O and none of them seem to work, can someone please help?

The project link is this one: https://github.com/LeoFragozo/leo_test, thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried to use user[name]/user_name in place of "name" in the fill_in and it dosen't seem to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's always easier if you add the actual rendered HTML to you question rather the erb template (the tests run against the rendered page not the template).  In your case it's likely that the name of your field in the page isn't actually `name` but is rather `user[name]` with an id of `user_name`.  Verify that in your page and then try

```
fill_in 'user_name', with: 'Leo' # or 'user[name]'
expect(page).to have_field('user_name', with: 'Leo') # or 'user[name]'
```

Comment: Ok i'm getting the same error, how i'm suppose to check the rendered html?

Comment: @AlmisKa Look at your project in a browser using the developer console

Comment: @AlmisKa. You can also just do something like `puts page.html` in your test to have it output the html to your console

Comment: I get it, btw i fixed it, it eas the route that was wrong lol, thanks for helping me !